# Write a forall constraint in CPLEX, indexing over a union of variables

Tags: indexing, cplex, forall

I'm modelling a routing problem in CPLEX opl. I am struggling to implement a certain constraint in CPLEX, which sums a decision variable X over a set of indexes j, and this ∀i ∈ V, where V = C ⋃ S.

The constraint is the following: sum(j ∈ (1..10)) Xij < 1 ∀i ∈ V
I implemented this in CPLEX as follows:

*forall(i in customers, i in stations) {*
*sum(j in reach) X[i][j] < 1; }*

*Customers* refers to C, *stations* refers to S, and *reach* refers to the range of 1..10.
However, it seems impossible to use the same index (i) twice in the forall statement.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
forall(i in customers, i in stations) { sum(j in reach) X[i][j] <= 0; }
```

you could write

```
forall(i in customers union stations) { sum(j in reach) X[i][j] <= 0; }
```

I tried

```
{int} customers={1,2};
{int} stations={2,3};

{int} reach={5};

dvar boolean X[customers union stations][reach];

subject to
{

forall(i in customers union stations) { sum(j in reach) X[i][j] <= 0; }

}
```

and that works

Comment: It may be useful to explicity define that set as the union of the other sets as that same set may be useful for other constraints, displaying or saving the solution etc. So try also defining {int} customersAndStations = customer union stations;

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! this indeed fixed my problem :)